# What happens if the level exit is crushed by spikes?

Tags: shovel-knight-pocket-dungeon

If you spend too much time in a level, spikes start coming down from the ceiling that destroys tiles in it's path. What happens if the spikes crush the level exit door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of crushing the door, the spikes will destroy whatever is on the tile beneath the exit to make room.